# Очистка структуры

Tags: c++, c

```
struct  RGB
{
    BYTE    rgbtBlue;
    BYTE    rgbtGreen;
    BYTE    rgbtRed;
} img[512*512];
```

Есть данная структура. Как её можно очистить?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 9):

Если нужно заполнить её нулями при создании тогда так:

```
RGB rgb = {};
```

Это эквивалентно следующему:

```
RGB rgb = {0, 0, 0};
```

Если нужно обнулить существующий объект структуры, тогда используем `memset`:

```
RGB rgb;
memset(&rgb, 0, sizeof(RGB));
```

Если нужно обнулить массив структур, тоггда делаем так:

```
memset(img, 0, sizeof(img))
```

Comment: Я думаю, вместо последней строчки имеловь в виду вот это: `memset(img, 0, sizeof(RGB) * 512 * 512)` - или это: `memset(img, 0, sizeof(img))` (первый способ работает в том числе с указателем на первый элемент, второй же - только с массивами).

Comment: @PavelMayorov, я просто описался с `img`. Спасибо - поправил.

Answer (score 7):

Так как у нас C++, а не C, предлагаю нормальное ООПное решение, а не "сишный путь" с обнулениями памяти по указателю.

Всё, что нужно сделать — это добавить конструктор:

```
struct RGB
{
    BYTE rgbtBlue;
    BYTE rgbtGreen;
    BYTE rgbtRed;

    RGB() : rgbtBlue(0), rgbtGreen(0), rgbtRed(0) { }
};

RGB img[512*512];
```

Если вы пользуетесь современным компилятором, то можете записать проще:

```
struct RGB
{
    BYTE rgbtBlue = 0;
    BYTE rgbtGreen = 0;
    BYTE rgbtRed = 0;
};
```

Ну а если вы хотите сэкономить на конструкторе, то просто запишите:

```
RGB img[512*512] = {};
```

Если вам нужно обнулить имеющуюся структуру, то можете воспользоваться `std::fill`:

```
std::fill(std::begin(img), std::end(img), RGB()); // идеально
std::fill(img, std::end(img), RGB());             // тоже сойдёт
std::fill(img, img + _countof(img), RGB());       // старый VC++
```

`memset` — это наследие от C. В C++ можно использовать языковые средства, а не полагаться на низкоуровневые операции с указателями и байтами.

Кроме того, `memset` не обладает идеальной кросс-платформенностью (впрочем, вы вряд ли встретитесь с таким железом), вы можете столкнуться с "неожиданностями" при добавлении полей сложных типов и так далее.

Comment: "memset — это костыль, который в общем случае не работает верно" - будут какие-то доказательства сему голословному утверждению?

Comment: @ixSci Стандарт не гарантирует, что 0 — это допустимое и нулевое значение для всех типов, в том числе для int, double и указателей. null может быть чем угодно, плавающие числа не обязаны быть IEEE, и так далее. Ну то есть на писюке на это нарваться сложно, конечно, но такие системы существуют. А memset — костыль хотя бы по той причине, что существуют конструкции на уровне языка, которые обнуляют память, причём делают это гарантированно корректно и кросс-платформенно, плюс ко всему кратко. Ну и у memset есть нюансы — пароли им не занулишь, компилятор может проигнорировать вызов.

Comment: "Стандарт не гарантирует, что 0 — это допустимое и нулевое значение для всех типов, в том числе для int" - Стандарт гарантирует представление Integer в бинарной форме, сиречь набором нулей и единиц. 0 есть 0 в любой системе счисления, хоть 10-ой, хоть бинароной, т.к. Вы не правы.  ""

Comment: "существуют конструкции на уровне языка, которые обнуляют память" - эти конструкции существуют только при инициализации, для всего остального есть `memset`. В общем, @Athari, Ваши рассуждения по-поводу `memset`, на мой взгляд, чрезвычайно теоретизированы и малоосновательны

Comment: memset с классами применять не стоит, потому что в них дополнительные данные могут находиться. Со структурами всё нормально.

Comment: Что это за измышления по поводу паролей? / По поводу же остального -- полностью согласен с @ixSci -- memset короче и  в любом случае понятней, поскольку явно привязан к месту действия, тогда как конструктор наоборот -- привязан к декларации. Впрочем, это давний спор об ООП.

Comment: @avp, по поводу паролей - есть такая штука, на самом деле. Вот [тут](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1381.pdf) можно почитать, к примеру.

Comment: @Qwertiy, `memset` нельзя применять с не-POD типами. С POD-типами всё нормально, вне зависимости от того, является ли тип структурой или классом.

Comment: @ixSci, прямо скажем -- **сами пароли здесь ни причем**. Автор статьи, приводя пример с паролем, остающимся в памяти,  просто драматизирует ситуацию, когда оптимизирующий компилятор выбрасывает лишний (с его т.з.) код.

Comment: @ixSci Курите http://stackoverflow.com/q/11138188 , http://stackoverflow.com/q/11994513 , http://stackoverflow.com/q/27714377 и остальное по тегу [language-lawyer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-lawyer).

Comment: @avp carbon-copy ^

Comment: @ixSci И я прекрасно понимаю, что конкретно для этой задачи можно использовать что угодно. Просто тыкать `memset` повсюду без разбора — это дурной тон. На следующий день добавишь строку в класс — и будет сюрприз. Если есть возможность оставаться в рамках языка, не обращаться к стандартной библиотеке — это надо делать.

Comment: @Athari, что значит в данном контексте `carbon-copy ^`? Пишите, пожалуйста, подоходчивей.

Comment: @avp Заголовок "CC" в email переводится как "[carbon copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_copy)". Шапочка — стрелка вверх. Это типа "см. предыдущее сообщение, отправленное другому пользователю (не могу включить в комментарий двух адресатов из-за ограничений движка)". Возможно, "CC" лучше узнаётся, но тут уже ограничение на размер сообщения возникает.

Comment: @Athari, опять умничаете? Кстати, а с чего Вы решили, что все тексты на SO всегда правильны и на них надо ссылаться без конкретных уточнений.

Comment: @avp В постах есть ссылки на стандарт. Можете обращаться к первоисточнику, если вам не нравится пояснительный текст на СО.

Comment: @Abyx Можете оформить в виде ответа, это достойно упоминания.

Comment: @Abyx То есть вы тоже за memset? И всё-таки что плохого в этом подходе?

Comment: @Athari, спасибо за ссылки. Я всё же остаюсь при своём мнении, что это чрезвычайно теоретические рассуждения. На английском SO ребята въедливые и я не сомневаюсь, что если они не нашли прямого упоминания о "0 это когда все биты сброшены", значит там его нет. Но стандарт это не закон мироздания и в нём тоже учтено не всё, сомневаюсь, что это сделано нарочно. Т.е. это просто упущение. Но с точки зрения стандарта Вы правы, да.

Comment: @Abyx В вопросе явно не указано, в какой момент надо "очищать" массив: то ли при инициализации, то ли позже. Если очищать нужно при инициализации, то у конструктора (или инициализаторов полей) есть какой-то недостаток? (Ну, кроме того, что компилятору оптимизировать такое сложнее — здесь я не в теме.)

Comment: @ixSci В стандарте C++ подобных "случайностей" не бывает. Просто что C, что C++ обладают самой впечатляющей переносимостью: если устройство есть, то есть компилятор C для него. Отсюда необходимость поддерживать всё на свете. Ну и в стандарте C явно описывается возможность паддинга в представлении целых чисел — вряд ли в стандарте C++ могли бы просто "забыть" про это. / Скажем так, подавляющему большинству программистов знания об этих странностях бесполезны. Я предпочитаю не использовать memset, если это возможно, не из-за того, что переносимость плохая, а потому что самого языка часто хватает.

Comment: Ну Бог с ним, пусть будет 0, состоящий не только из нуль-битов. Это ведь ничего не изменит, кроме дефиниции нуля. И код из Вашего ответа, и `memset` использует понятие нуля. Т.е. нулевая константа всё равно остаётся 0, вне зависимости от того, как этот ноль представлен.

Comment: @ixSci У разных типов ноль может быть разный, а memset интерпретирует память как последовательность unsigned char (для которого бинарное представление задано точно, кстати, то есть по сути все биты устанавливаются в 0, есть передать 0).

Comment: Я к чему это всё - я предлагаю смягчить фразу про `memset` в ответе, на что-то более нейтральное(не C++-way, к примеру). Но убрать слово "костыль", не является эта функция костылём.

Comment: @ixSci Обновил. Также добавил информацию из комментариев.

Comment: Ура, дискуссия о стандарте C++! #languagelawyer #крестопроблемы

Comment: @VladD Это ещё не крестопроблемы. Я постеснялся написать `std::fill(img, img + sizeof(img) / sizeof(img[0]), RGB());` :)

Comment: @Athari: А почему? `std::fill` как бе стандартный инструмент. Хотя неявная инициализация мне кажется изящнее. (А неужели нету стандартного макроса/шаблона `_countof` или как его там?)

Comment: @VladD Макрос `_countof` есть, а но он не стандартный. Ждём стандартную шаблонную функцию `size()` в C++17... http://www.g-truc.net/post-0708.html

Comment: @Abyx О, вижу. Интересно, почему в гугле не всплыло... Исправил. Но я так погляжу, версия с `constexpr` и VC++ не очень дружат... Вообще, я на плюсах со школы не писал, я просто почитываю статейки время от времени. Отсюда и сильный перекос в сторону категории знаний "а знаете ли вы, что" в ущерб категории знаний "есть такая функция" и реальных практических навыков. Просто стараюсь, чтобы знания плюсов окончательно не протухли — мало ли, где может понадобится.

Comment: А вот если вдруг нужно будет занулить массив структур в обратном порядке, то использовать `std::rend(img)` не получится. В C++11 функции `rbegin()` и `rend()` забыли добавить. Вспомнили только в C++14. А вы говорите в стандарте не бывает случайностей...

Comment: Я, кстати, за конструктор, если что. Просто потому, что `memset` не решает задачу. В плюсах, когда мы говорим "очистить", мы подразумеваем "инициализировать через конструктор по умолчанию". Мы ни в коем случае не имеем в виду вульгарное заполнение памяти нулями. И даже если конструктор по умолчанию  по факту заполняет память нулями, вовсе не факт, что это всё, что он делает. Возможно, он ещё регистрирует созданные объекты в каком-нибудь пуле (синглтоне), например.